# Set Timeline Cover in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Suppose that I am able to upload a photo to user's album, how can it be set to as Timeline Cover. There are some apps who already doing that like myfbcovers.com and firstcovers.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with the profile picture, apps are **NOT** allowed to set the cover picture (yet?). The websites you linked to just upload the selected image to your wall (inside the application album **NOT** the cover album) and ask you to set it manually!

Answer (score 1):

I actually just finished up on the same app your working on.
You can not set the cover photo with an application at the moment. Facebook used to allow it but quickly removed this option. Now, only the user can set his/her cover from Profile View. I have no idea why, probably security precautions.

Source: FB app developer of http://fbcoverlover.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cover photo for a Page by issuing an HTTP POST to '/PAGE_ID/' with a Page Access Token and the following parameters:

- cover         - The ID of the photo. Integer. Mandatory.
- offset_y      - The percentage offset from top (0-100). The default value is 50. Integer. Optional.
- no_feed_story - The flag indicating whether or not to create a story. The default value is false. Boolean. Optional

Answer (score 1):

after you uploaded the photo to the users album you get the photo id as response. you can then redirect the user to the following link to set that pictures as his cover photo:

https://www.facebook.com/[USER_ID]?preview_cover=[PICTURE_ID]

he will see his profile with the picture as his cover and two buttons "save cover" or "cancel".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, previously there was a way that our [facebook covers](http://www.myfbcovers.com) application used to do this but they removed it for some reason.